# HashMap data to listView using custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am new to Android development and am trying to get JSON data including two text pieces of data and one image piece of data into **LISTVIEW** and NOT imageView. I came to realize all data is being stored in caridList which is a HashMap.

Any suggestions as to how to fix these errors along with a description are greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why? Oh why? There is a Simpleadapter for this (Map<String, Object>... Plus eventually custom ViewBinder

Comment: @Selvin I am new to Android development and this is my first app so despite great amounts of research, I am not aware of a Simpleadapter.  Any suggestions are appreciated pertaining to the errors. Thanks.

Comment: @Selvin I am looking to the Simpleadapter. How can I add data dynamically?

Comment: How is this code even compiling? You have declared an ArrayList variable as caridlist, and also written a static class caridlist. How does that even work? I've been working with java so long. and I cant even figure out how it is compiling in the first place.

Comment: @SamratDutta It does not even compile. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: Yes. it should not compile. There is a lot wrong with this code. I would politely suggest that you please first learn java well and then come into android. As of this error. I can fix it. But it will take a lot of time, and a complete reshuffle. If you want, I can post a possibly working solution. But I would still suggest that you leave this and focus on java first. :)

Comment: And, always try to use separate files for separate classes, and avoid using inner classes until they are absolutely necessary.

Comment: @SamratDutta I am trying my hardest to learn Java as well. I understand that a firm understanding of Java first would be of great help, but unfortunately, I have to juggle Java and Android development at the same time for a reason that I would not like to state here. I am still trying my hardest to learn both at a good pace. And, I will keep your tip in mind. However, I would greatly greatly appreciate if you could, as you said, post a possibly working solution. I have spent many many hours on this and it is difficult to grasp all of the errors. Please sir.

Comment: @JohnWilliams For now, can you implement the answer that jakubbailkowski has given? That should solve your problem. And you should be able to get this thing working. If you have any trouble understanding how to implement it, do tell me. As he said, you can make a seperate pojo class of Car and then add that to your ArrayList. For now, just change the class caridlist to cardata as he mentioned. And follow his instructions, make the other changes. I am really sorry, that I asked you to leave the project without considering your situation. that was impolite of me.

Comment: If that doesn't work, just comment here, and check back tomorrow. I will do what I promised. Its just that where I live, its 3 in the morning, and I have a seminar tomorrow. I hope you will understand. But I promise, I will post an answer if the other solution doesn't work out. Just try it out and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @SamratDutta Hello. I have been attempting to apply the solution provided below, but I am running into an issue and am confused. I would greatly appreciate your help, sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You made few mistakes in this snippet.

First there is no need to use Map for storing your data

You should create [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) or other object for storing your data.

So create class called **CarData**

```
public class CarData {

    public String carId;
    public String carVin;
    public String modelImg;

    public CarData(String carId, String carVin, String modelImg) {
        this.carId = carId;
        this.carVin = carVin;
        this.modelImg = modelImg;
    }
}
```

Next instead of having field:

```
//Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> caridList;
```

use

```
List<CarData> carDataList = new ArrayList<CarData>();
```

in **AsyncTask** instead of putting Strings to Map, you should create new **CarData** and add to list

```
CarData carData = new CarData(car_id, car_vin, model_img);
carDataList.add(carData);
```

Your ArrayAdapter class declaration should look like:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CarData>
```

Keep your data into list:

```
private List<CarData> list;
```

In **getView**:

```
CarData item = getItem(position);

....

holder.car_id.setText(item.carId);
holder.car_vin.setText(item.carVin);
```

To load image into ImageView check Picasso or [Glide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

**EDIT**

Replace this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < carid.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = carid.getJSONObject(i);
      String car_id = c.getString(TAG_CARID);
      Log.d("car_id", car_id);

      String car_vin = c.getString(TAG_CARVIN);
      Log.d("car_vin", car_vin);

      String model_img = c.getString(TAG_IMG);
      Log.d("model_img", model_img);

      //Hashmap for single match
      HashMap<String, Object> matchGetCars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      //Log.v("Item 3", item.toString());
      //Adds each child node to HashMap key => value
      matchGetCars.put(TAG_CARID, car_id);
      matchGetCars.put(TAG_CARVIN, car_vin);
      matchGetCars.put(TAG_IMG, model_img);
      caridList.add(matchGetCars);
      Log.v("CaridList", caridList.toString());
}
```

with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < carid.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = carid.getJSONObject(i);
    String car_id = c.getString(TAG_CARID);
    String car_vin = c.getString(TAG_CARVIN);
    String model_img = c.getString(TAG_IMG);
    CarData carData = new CarData(car_id, car_vin, model_img);
    carDataList.add(carData);
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response! Where should the following code be placed: CarData carData = new CarData(car_id, car_vin, model_img);
            carDataList.add(carData); ? I am not understanding.

Comment: You can declare it as nested class or you can create new one in separate file. I would go in second way, you should decouple your code as much as possible.

Comment: Place this code in doInBackground() in your for loop. Replace HashMap creating with provided code

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your tips. When the app ran the image did not come in listView and the logcat stated SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null. I am looking into it now, but any suggestions would be appreciated. I will post my revised code above. Thanks.

Comment: After quick revision, it seems that you are trying to load json into imageview, try with image url from CarData: modelImg

Comment: I am trying to load a JSON image into ListView. Like this: Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.model_img); ?

Comment: I receive these errors: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
07-27 11:22:46.795    8109-8171/com.example.justin.myapplication D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
07-27 11:22:48.834    8109-8187/com.example.justin.myapplication D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: Is there any way to set the image resource in getView after the else statement and NOT use Picasso? I tried   holder.model_img.setImageResource(item.modelImg); also, but 'setImageResource(int)' in 'android.widget.ImageView' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'.

Comment: Have you tried look into url addresses of images? They are incorrect, so you should not be surprised that image with url like `/images/image.php?w=200&img=cars/GZTLVONAJXORVAZTMCVBSCOSPVAZZDKFCDRYSFZCCNTYOSRAVM.jpg` is not displaying.